# How do I keep my navigation bar sticky after passing another list?

Tags: html, css

I've been working on the HTML website that I'm designing for a class and up until this point I've mainly been relying on sites like w3schools to help me with it. I added in a sticky nav bar using the list method in HTML and CSS and it worked fine on my main page, but on my other page, it stops being sticky once it hits another list I made. I was wondering if there was a way to get it to still stick when scrolling past the lists.

To see if it was definitely the list that was causing the issue, I took the list on the second page and put it on the first and I had the same issue. I also tried changing the unordered list I used for the nav bar to an ordered list to see if it was some sort of tag issue, but still the same result. I've only used HTML and CSS before, but if the solution requires any use of JS or jQuery, I'd be interested in hearing it.

My markup:

```css
.ul1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #66CDAA;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: #B0E0E6;
  border-width: 10;
}

.li1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.a1 {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #F0FFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.a1:hover {
  background-color: #B0E0E6;
  transition-duration: 0.9s;
}

.active {
  background-color: #136c68;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul1" style="font-family:courier new; font-size:20 px">
  <li class="li1"><a class="a1" href="index.html">Home/Index</a></li>
  <li class="li1"><a class="a1 active" href="hobby.html">Hobby</a></li>
</ul>
```

Markup causing the issue:

```html
  <ul style="font-size:18px;">
<li>The Mass Effect Trilogy</li>
<li>Minecraft</li> 
<li>Portal (1 & 2)</li>  
<li>Dishonored (1 & 2)</li>   
<li>Astroneer</li>  
<li>Octopath Traveler</li>
<li>Pokémon Diamond</li>
<li>Don't Starve</li>   
   </ul>
```

Mentioned this in the comments, but I also put it into a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/annetheginger/pen/vwBeQv) if that will help.

I want to be able to scroll the whole way down on the site and see the nav bar sticking at the top. I can add more code if this isn't enough. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is confusing and not complete... but normally things that have to stay on top are placed in the header of the document...

Comment: Should I add the rest of my HTML to show what's going on in the code snippet?

Comment: At least post the other list that is causing the problem. Although I suspect the problem is you are using the same `class` for both lists.

Comment: Added it in after the first section, I also put it into [CodePen](https://codepen.io/annetheginger/pen/vwBeQv) so that people can see it better if that will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a less obvious behavior of `sticky` that the documentation usually doesn't make clear: the 'sticky' property only goes as far down as the containing element. That is, it will not move below its container.

Therefore, to get the "permanent" sticky behavior I imagine you want, you should add the sticky `<ul>` directly to the `<body>` element. Otherwise it will only `sticky` itself as far down as its containing `<center>` element whichs ends just above yout content list...

Answer (score 0):

Try not to wrap the sticky `<ul>` within `<center></center>`.
If you want the content to be in center try using `text-align` property wrapping the text between `<div></div>`